# error parsing xml response string in php

Tags: php, xml, drupal

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
<soap:Envelope 
    xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"> 
    <soap:Body> 
        <GetListItemsResponse xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/"> 
            <GetListItemsResult> 
                <listitems xmlns:s='uuid:BDC6E3F0-6DA3-11d1-A2A3-00AA00C14882' 
                           xmlns:dt='uuid:C2F41010-65B3-11d1-A29F-00AA00C14882' 
                           xmlns:rs='urn:schemas-microsoft-com:rowset' 
                           xmlns:z='#RowsetSchema'> 
                    <rs:data ItemCount="2"> 
                        <z:row ows_ID='1' ows_MetaInfo='1;#vti_parserversion:SR|14.0.0.6134&#13;&#10;' /> 
                            <z:row ows_ID='2' ows_MetaInfo='2;#vti_parserversion:SR|14.0.0.6134&#13;&#10;' />
                    </rs:data> 
                </listitems> 
            </GetListItemsResult> 
        </GetListItemsResponse> 
    </soap:Body> 
</soap:Envelope>
```

XML string

What i want to get is `ItemCount` attribute from `rs:data` node

what i am trying is

```
$dom = new DOMDocument; $dom->loadXML( $result->data ); $xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);

$seats = $xpath->query('//rs:data[@ItemCount]'); print_r($seats);
```

Please help as i am new to Drupal PHP with right way to get the value for `itemcount` attribute from that `rs:data` node. I have tried many ways even using simplexml but none worked, please share the code snippet

Thanks

Comment: Looks like the `ows_MetaInfo`-attributes are missing the closing apostrophe?

Comment: Actually that node had too much data i had just removed excessive data attributes from that node, as that was not relevant , otherwise xml is fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you dont need to parse it as xml, to get one value I think it would be better to use `preg_match_all` like this.

```
preg_match_all('/rs:data ItemCount="(.*?)"/', $string, $match);
```

[working example](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/30ac969d4237733a26415cf298935b2fc1a97bf9)